# How to Solve a FieldError- Cannot resolve keyword 'slug' into field

Tags: python, django

I'm making a Post and Comment model. I created and Post and Comment model and it looks ok. I can add post and also comment to any particular post.
I am trying to give the option for every user who made a comment to delete it

Here is the views.py

```
def delete_comment(request):
    id = request.POST['comment_id']
    pk = request.POST['post_id']
    if request.method == 'POST':
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment, id=id, pk=pk)
        try:
            comment.delete()
            messages.success(request, 'You have successfully deleted the comment')

        except:
            messages.warning(request, 'The comment could not be deleted.')

    return redirect('blog:post-detail')
```

Here is the template:

```
                        <form action = "{% url 'blog:post-commentd' %}" method = "POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" value="{{ comment.id }}"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id }}"/>
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1">Delete</button>
                        </form>
```

Here is the url

```
    path('blog/delete_comment/',
         delete_comment, name='post-commentd'),
```

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='author')
    slug = models.SlugField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=120)

class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(max_length=300, validators=[validate_comment_text])
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? Delete a *single* comment? or delete *all* comments associated with a post?

Comment: I want to give the user who added a comment the option to delete it

Comment: In your `blog/<slug:slug>/delete_comment/` end-point, you are grabbing more than one comments associated with a Post. In short, your `PostCommentDeleteView` is a **list view** rather than a *detail view*

Comment: @ArakkalAbu I've updated my code from CBV to a function because as u said it is getting a list view, but I am getting a 404 error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you I would use a link instead of a form to delete the comment and ensure only the author of the comment sees the delete button. This is how I would attempt to do it.

```
{% if comment.name == user.username %}

   <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm mt-1 mb-1" 
   onclick="location.href='{% url 'blog:delete-comment' comment.id 
   %}';">Delete</button>

{% endif %}
```

My URL should be something like this

```
    path('blog/delete_comment/<int:id>/',
         views.delete_comment, name='delete-comment'),
```

Then my views.py

```
@login_required
def delete_comment(request,id):
   
        comment = get_object_or_404(Comment,id=id)
        slug    = comment.post.slug
    
        try:
            if request.user == comment.user:
               comment.delete()
               messages.success(request, 'You have successfully deleted the 
                                         comment')

        except:
            messages.warning(request, 'The comment could not be deleted.')

    return redirect('blog:post-detail', slug)
```

Comment: I am getting `delete_comment() got an unexpected keyword argument 'pk'` error. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry let me fix it up there

Comment: I am trying to set the redirect to return to the same page after clicking delete but it is not working `return redirect('blog:post-detail' self.Post.slug)`

Comment: try this we see if we can get the post slug from the comment
```slug = comment.post.slug

return redirect('blog:post-detail'  slug)
```
put the slug variable under the comment then we see